# Expected value and variance of number of successes minus number of failures

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

This is one of my friends homework question. I tried to solve it and explain to him but I couldn't solve it. The question is simple.

Let $
X_n = (\text{# of successes}) - (\text{# of failures}) 
$

in $n$ Bernoulli trials with possibility of success = $p$, and possibility of failure = $(1-p)$ for each of the Bernoulli trials. Find $E[X_n]$ and $Var[X_n]$.

My attempt to find the PMF of $X_n$ is the following:

$
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    p^n,                            & \text{if } x=n   \\
    p^{n-1}(1-p)^1 \binom{n}{n-1},  & \text{if } x=n-2 \\
    p^{n-2}(1-p)^2 \binom{n}{n-2},  & \text{if } x=n-4 \\
    \vdots                          & \vdots           \\
    (1-p)^n,                        & \text{if } x=-n \\
    0     & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

More compactly,

$
    f(n-i)= 
\begin{cases}
    p^{(n-\frac{i}{2})} (1-p)^{(\frac{i}{2})}\binom{n}{n-\frac{i}{2}},       & \text{if } 0 \leq i \leq 2n \text{ and } i \% 2 = 0 \\
    0     & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

And using this PMF, expected value will be:

$
\begin{align}
  E[x] &= \sum_{i} i f(i) \\
       &= \sum_{i \in {0 \leq i \leq 2n \text{ and } i \% 2 = 0}} (n-i)  p^{(n-\frac{i}{2})} (1-p)^{(\frac{i}{2})}\binom{n}{n-\frac{i}{2}}
\end{align}
$

This is where I got stuck. I feel like there is a simpler way to solve this.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a direct relationship between the number of successes and the number of failures given a fixed $n$ trials. The sum of failures and successes equals $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\#failures = n - \#successes$, thus $X_n = 2\, \#successes - n$.
Since we know that $Y_n := \#successes \sim Binomial(n, p)$, we have that 
$$ E[X_n] = 2 \,E[Y_n] - n  = 2np - n $$
and 
$$ Var(X_n) = 4 \,Var(Y_n) = 4np(1-p). $$